# Что включено в процесс инициализации класса?

Tags: java, классы, jvm, heap

Конкретно на примере:
 1. Впервые с момента запуска программы обратились к static-члену (тип int) класса.
 2. Произошла инициализация этого класса (выполнение static-блока и т. д.).
 3. Обращаемся в static-методу этого-же класса. **Вот именно в этот момент, откуда Java получает тело метода (команды): из .class файла на жёстком диске или из  оперативной памяти?**

*То есть, при инициализации класса без создания объектов, из .class файла в другую область (скажем, оперативную память) попадает вообще вся информация из класса или только часть информации? Если только часть, то попадают ли: тела методов? то, что после `=` у instance-полей?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретно на ваш вопрос - из памяти. Если в момент работы запущенного приложения вы поменяете class то по умолчаню Java его не подхватит. ClassLoader загружает все классы в момент запуска приложения. Не путайте загрузку класса и его инициализацию. Инициализация произойдет после первого обращения. Можете посмотреть вот эти ссылки: http://java-online.ru/java-classloader.xhtml, https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/646-kak-proiskhodit-zagruzka-klassov-v-jvm, https://habr.com/ru/post/103830/,https://habr.com/ru/post/104229/,